# В качестве ловушки показывается вопрос, на который я отвечал

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, аудит

Собственно, вот:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/73862

Я помню этот вопрос, я помню даже свой ответ на него про флаг и директиву.

Неужели кто-то будет голосовать за закрытие вопроса, на который он сам отвечал?
Какая-то заведомо провальная проверка получается :(

Comment: Подумайте об этом, как о проверке, удалось ли сообществу вас перевоспитать. Я очень рад, что многие вопросы, на которые я отвечал закрыты, а многие я сам удалял.

Comment: "Неужели...?" **Да:** http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470785/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/470789#470789

Comment: @D-side, вот это поворот!

Comment: @Nofate, происки путинских холуев :-D

Answer (score 12):

Не надо воспринимать проверки как нечто сложное. Задача проверок — убедиться, что пользователь думает перед тем, как нажимать на кнопки, а не считает ворон. Соответственно, если вы помните, что ответили на какой-то вопрос, то поздравляю, вы прошли проверку.

И таки есть пользователи, которые голосуют за закрытие вопросов, на которые отвечают. Ответ на закрытый вопрос всё равно приносит плюсы, да и пофлудить в оффтопичных вопросах бывает приятно. Наказания за ответы на оффтопик тоже нет, по сути.

Comment: Но ведь это не вопрос с флудом. Т. е. мне проверка "проголосуй за закрытие вопроса, на который ответил и который считаешь нормальным" кажется заведомо проваленной (как раз в случае, когда пользователь думает перед тем как нажать кнопку). Логично было бы исключить такие вопросы из ловушек, нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Отвечать на оффтопичные вопросы не запрещено (жаль, конечно, что это так), поэтому из того, что юзер написал ответ, не следует, что он будет голосовать в очереди на закрытие каким-то образом.